# Natural sort order in C# - implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

I'd like to implement a natural sorting using this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByAlphaNumeric<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, string> selector)
{
    int max = source
        .SelectMany(i => Regex.Matches(selector(i), @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => (int?)m.Value.Length))
        .Max() ?? 0;

    return source.OrderBy(i => Regex.Replace(selector(i), @"\d+", m => m.Value.PadLeft(max, '0')));
}
```

(taken from [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp))

I have a `dataview dv` which contains (among others) a column `code_name`. I'd like to copy the data of this dataview into a new `datatable dtNew` with a natural sort on the column `code_name`. I guess the code should be something like:

```
DataTable dtNew = dv.Table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("code_name"),OrderByAlphaNumeric<T>).CopyToDataTable();
```

But I don't understand anything in how to manipulate `IEnumerable<T> OrderByAlphaNumeric<T>` in my context.

Comment: Replace your `OrderBy` with `OrderByAlphaNumeric`.

Comment: Do you mean `DataTable dtNew = dv.Table.AsEnumerable().OrderByAlphaNumeric(x => x.Field<string>("code_name")).CopyToDataTable();`? It doesn't work (error "does not contain a definition for and no extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)").

Comment: Yes, that's what you'd write. Not sure why you're getting an error - its likely you haven't referenced your extension class. What is the type it's looking for? (but it in backticks - ` - otherwise it's stripped from the comment)

Comment: I've changed as suggested. But implementation is also one of my issues, I don't know how to implement this "public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByAlphaNumeric<T> [...]". Should I create in folder "AppCode" a class named OrderByAlphaNumeric.cs? What should be the namespace in this class, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use it like this:

```
DataTable dtNew = dv.Table.AsEnumerable().OrderByAlphaNumeric(x => x.Field<string>("code_name")).CopyToDataTable();
```

Be sure to open the namespace containing `OrderByAlphaNumeric` where you use this code.